# Power series of $1/(1-x-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a difficulty in finding the power series of: $$\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$$ At first I did a polynomial division and I found out that: $$\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}=1+x+2x+3x^2+5x^3+8x^4+13x^5+...$$ where the coefficients of this Taylor Series are the numbers of the Fibonacci Sequence.
However, this is not a proof, so when I tried to prove it, I reached the following point:$$\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x+x^2)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n(1+x)^n\\ =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{2n-k}$$
How can I proceed from this point, or I have to take another path?

Comment: Do you know about partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Of course I do, but my attempt is to solve the problem in a more interesting way than that. Therefore, I am seeking for a way to connect the sum I concluded with something related to the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: That's interesting! You have written the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Generating_function) of the Fibonacci sequence divided by $x$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Mathematics

Comment: "However, this is not a proof"... why is that no proof? LHS is holomorphic around zero hence it has a power series representation, hence the formal power series on the RHS you derived actually converges for small enough $x$ to the LHS.

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition gives you two geometric series, the coefficients of like terms summing to the Fibonacci sequence. Those coefficients are functions of $n$, so the result is a formula for the nth Fibonacci term.

Comment: @PeterMüller I did not consider it as a proof because I did not show that the coefficients of the series will continue to be the Fibonacci Numbers, I wanted something more. Now, regarding what you said about holomorphic around zero, this is something that I do not know and I do not understand for now, because I am in my first year in the University.

Comment: Regarding "a more interesting way": Please do not harbor hidden requirements for answers. It's too hard to guess what those requirements might be. Instead, make the requirements explicit in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to continue from your approach. Let's fix a natural number $N$ and compute its coefficient. Given $n$, the inner sum can only contribute terms with powers $n, n+1, \ldots, 2n$. So to compute the coefficient of $x^{N}$, we should consider those terms with $n = N/2, N/2 + 1, \ldots N$. It now makes a difference whether $N$ is even or odd - let's assume it's even for simplicity.

The coefficient of $x^{N}$ is

$$\binom{N/2}{0} + \binom{N/2+1}{2} + \ldots + \binom{N}{N} = \sum_{i=0}^{N/2} \binom{N/2+i}{2i}$$

A similar argument for $N$ odd gives

$$\binom{(N+1)/2}{1} + \binom{(N+3)/2}{3} + \ldots \binom{N}{N}$$

Let's call these sums $S_{N}$. Sorry for the overloaded notation - assuming again that $N$ is even, so $N+1$ is odd, We can write $S_{N}+S_{N+1}$ as:

\begin{align*}
\binom{N/2}{0} + \binom{N/2+1}{2} + \ldots + \binom{N}{N} + \\
\binom{N/2 + 1}{1} + \binom{N/2+2}{3} + \ldots + \binom{N + 1}{N} \\
= \binom{N/2}{0} + \binom{N/2+2}{2} + \binom{N/2+3}{4} + \ldots \binom{N+1}{N+1}
\end{align*}

(applying Pascal's identity), and luckily $\binom{N/2}{0} = 1 = \binom{N/2 + 1}{0}$, so this final sum is indeed $S_{N+2}$. It remains to check the case $N$ odd, and that $S_{0} = S_{1} = 1$, but those checks are easy.

There is a more compelling approach: Assume we can write $\frac{1}{1-x-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n}$.

Then, multiplying by $1-x-x^2$,

\begin{align*}
1 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} (1-x-x^2)x^{n}\\
&= a_{0} + a_{1} x - a_{0}x + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (a_{n} - a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) x^n \\
\end{align*}

and we deduce, by equating coefficients, that

\begin{align*}
a_0 &= 1 \\
a_1 &= a_0 \\
a_n &= a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \,\,\text{for $n \ge 2$}
\end{align*}

and hence, that $(a_n)$ are the Fibonacci numbers.